# Mongodb fetch multiple _id queries together

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a couple of _id parameters whose matching documents I would like to fetch.
What is the best way to do this.

I prefer to solve this at the database layer rather than in the business logic.

Eg :

```
var getPostById = function(id)
{
    var result = false;
    opinion.findOne({_id : id}, function(err, data)
    {
        result = data;
    });
    return result;
},

var arr = [];
var _idList = [41415123,31512512,45213123123];
for(var len = _idList.length; len > 0; len--) {
    arr.push(getPostById(_idList[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/):

```
opinion.find({_id : { $in : _idList } }, ...);
```

PS, be sure to read up on how asynchronous calls work in Node, your `getPostById` function as you post it wouldn't work because it returns `result` before the query has completed.

Comment: Thanks mate, althought I didn't realize there was an exactly same question with the same answer here. And about the loop; it was just an example. I use the async library in my code.